# iOS - Searching a SQLite database is slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Hi I have built a dictionary application my data base has 78.000 record , so when I trying to search through data base the searching process is not smooth and you feel some delay ! specially when try to type first letter when app lunched . here is my codes , I would be grateful if help me to find a solution :

**Searching :**

```
  - (void)searchWord:(NSString *)txt{

        sqlite3_exec(database, "REINDEX table;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    NSMutableArray *DB_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *dbPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [self getDBPath]];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

//      @"SELECT * FROM DIC WHERE NAME !=  '%@%%' ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 30"
//      SELECT * FROM DIC  Where Name LIKE '%@%%' order by NAME LIMIT 30

        NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID,NAME FROM DIC WHERE NAME LIKE  '%@%%' ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 15",txt];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger oid = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

                const char* f1 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                NSString *oName = f1 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f1];

//                NSLog(@"%@",oName);

                const char* f2 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
                NSString *oMean = f2 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f2];


                const char* f3 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);
                NSString *oPron = f3 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f3];

                NSInteger bm = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 5);

                readerClass = [[Reader alloc]initWithReadDB:oid Name:oName Mean:oMean Pron:oPron bookMark:bm];

                [DB_Array addObject:readerClass];

            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving data from database.");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Error: Can't open database!");
        NSLog(@" DB Name %@",viewController.dbName);
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegateClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegateClass.wordList removeAllObjects];
    [appDelegateClass.wordList=DB_Array mutableCopy];
    [appDelegateClass setCurrentDBPath:[dbPath UTF8String]];

}
```

**TableView :**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    appClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%d",appClass.wordList.count);
    return  appClass.wordList.count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    appClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    readerClass = (Reader *)[appClass.wordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text  = readerClass.Name;


    return cell;
}
```

SearchBar :

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if([searchText length] > 0) {

        dbClass=[[DB alloc]init];
        [dbClass searchWord:searchText];

    }else

    {
        dbClass=[[DB alloc]init];
        [dbClass searchWord:@" "];
    }

    [self.myTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: One UI idea is to first get a count for the query.  If its above some large threshold, set state that indicates this.  When search is active and this state is set, give the search results table just one cell that says "40 zillion results.  please keep typing".

Comment: Performing a "like" query against 78k records will be slow. Not much you can do. It *might* be better to use the `substr` function instead of `like`. Or it might be better to implement your own custom "starts with" function.

Comment: It might also help, at least for this use case, to split the table up into 26 tables, one for each letter. Then based on what the user types, you look at the first letter and search that specific letter table. The query will be faster since it will have far fewer rows.

Comment: @rmaddy - Good ideas (especially the partition) to speed the query, but there's no point in filling memory with (and a table virtually with) more data than a user can be expected to scroll quickly.